# Is this a correct usage of the word "recurring"?

Tags: word-usage

> After a month's attendance, I noticed how the teacher used a recurring approach to introduce some of the key words.

I'm trying to convey that the teacher used this particular method repeatedly across her lessons, is "recurring" a suitable word?

Comment: You could simply say that the teacher  used *the same  approach* during all the lesson.

Comment: More natural would be *...used a **consistent** approach*.

Answer (score -1):

No recurring is definitely not the word you are looking for...

i think the a semi-official term is "repetitive method"

https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803100414691

Answer (score -1):

Your phrase implies that the approach, even if taken only once, was in some way recurrent. Instead I understand that all you want to say is that the teacher *repeatedly* used the same method.

---

> More natural would be ...*used a [consistent](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/consistent) approach*. – **FumbleFingers** 2 hours ago

Shameless reputation stealing from comment answers is very much encouraged by the rules. However, I'm personally a bit puzzled by the missing semantic link from "to consist", and I assume it's closer to *insist*, *resist* (*hesitate*? As a second language learner I often said *?hesistant*, but always fumbled when forming the verb).

I suppose *consistent* in this sense originally meant *fitting, selected to fit, joined*, if the German nouns *Konsistenz* <sup>[1]</sup> ~ *Zusammensetzung* <sup>[2]</sup> are any indication: *zusammensetzen* means "set together, assemble, sit together"; also cp *concept*, *conceptual*, *conceived*.

After all, the that's saying more than is intended. But it is undeniably idiomatic as it goes.

<sub>1: Konsitenz - the structure of a thing, e.g. of food, which may be creamy, chewy, gnarly, chunky, ... One might say my answer lacks any Konsistenz, because it runs like liquid through a sieve.</sub>

<sub>2: Zusammensetzung - "consistency, composition, structure"; not to be confused with *Zusammensellung* "composition, compilation".</sub>

---

I have to refer back to your phrase, because, in fact, learning thrives in recurrence. In some sense, a recurrent method makes sense. At first, *introduction* seems to be a one-shot that can't be repeated, or divided. However, teaching also involves teaching the methods, not just the results (give a man a fish and he will be fine for a day, teach him to fish and he will be fine for much longer).

---

My above allusion to togetherness, assemblage, collection fits also in the sense that *assemble* as well as Ger *zusammen*, *sammeln* mightbreflect PIE *sem- "together; one"; *assemble* as well as *sammeln* also mean "to collected", so a sense of *selected* becomes apparent. However, drawing from German *einheitlich*, which describes a consistently applied method, akin to *Einheit* "unit" (*ein-* is "one; a, an"), then consider all of dict.cc's translations, some of which fit better than others:

```
    consistent {adj}
coherent {adj} [consistent]     
uniform {adj}       
unified {adj}   
homogeneous {adj}   
unitary {adj}   
uniformly {adv} [unvaryingly]   
consistently {adv} [uniformly]  
even {adj}  
integrative {adj}   
single {adj} [unitary]  
standardized {adj}  
standardised {adj} [Br.]    
*lawspec.* unital {adj} 
unitarily {adv}
```